# Suggestions for printing debug messages from OpenCL kernel to file?

Tags: debugging, printing, opencl

I'm having a larger OpenCL project here. Currently I'm printing debug messages to the console.
It would be nice to have this Debug messages in a file.

Anyone has an idea how to get the printstream of the OpenCL kernel and deflect it to a file?

Or maybe a better idea for handling debug messages?

Answer (score 3):

The OpenCL specification states that the output of `printf` is sent to an implementation-defined output stream. There is no way to programatically control where this output goes.

If you are running the program from a terminal/console environment, you can achieve the effect you want by including a unique string inside your OpenCL `printf` calls and filtering the output when you run the program. For example, in your kernel code, you could have `printf` calls like this:

```
kernel void foo(...)
{
  ...
  printf("OCL: ...", ...);
  ...
}
```

When you run the program, you can then redirect just the OpenCL `printf` calls to a file with a command like this:

```
(Unix)
./foo | grep "^OCL: " >ocl_debug.txt

(Windows)
foo | findstr "OCL: " >ocl_debug.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

As output stream of OpenCL is implementation-defined, you have 2 options to get it into file. First is already proposed by **jprice**, second is to redirect all output into file

```
./opencl_app &>./file.txt
```

Let me ask a question: order of printf outputs isn't guaranteed to be same to order of it's calls. Is it really helpful in big project debugging? If you're using printf, my guess is that your platform is AMD or Intel. Both vendors provide handy debuggers, which can be used inside the kernel.

Comment: Yes, I will dig deeper in the AMD debugger but it is nice to have some general, easy to access information about the general state.

Comment: On AMD machines I make use of AMD CodeXL, GPU Debugger component inside CodeXL is pretty handy in debugging the OpenCL Kernels download it here : http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/opencl-tools-sdks/codexl/